# React renders an empty array item on mount, how can I avoid that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm once again here asking for help, I have this component that renders an empty array item on mount, how can I avoid that and conditionally render a `<p>` tag that tells the user there's no items in the array yet? I have tried this code but it didn't work. This is my component (I know I have to refactor it, I just want to make it work first):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
const formatThousands = require("format-thousands")

const Clients = () => {
  const [client, setClient] = useState({})
  const [allClients, setAllClients] = useState([])
  const [name, setName] = useState("")
  const [cuota, setCuota] = useState("")
  const [id, setId] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    setAllClients([...allClients, client])
  }, [client])

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (!name || !cuota || !id) return
    setClient({ ...client, name, cuota, id })
    setName("")
    setCuota("")
    setId("")
  }
  function handleDeleteButton(id) {
    allClients.filter(cl => id !== cl.id)
  }
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form className="input-group" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <span className="input-group-text">Nuevo cliente</span>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Agregar un nuevo cliente"
          value={name}
          onChange={event => setName(event.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="Monto cuota"
          className="form-control"
          value={cuota}
          onChange={event => setCuota(event.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="number"
          placeholder="identificador"
          className="form-control"
          value={id}
          onChange={event => setId(event.target.value)}
        />
        <button className="btn btn-success" type="submit">
          Agregar
        </button>
      </form>
      <div className="text-center my-2">
        <h3>Clientes</h3>
      </div>
      <table className="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
            <th scope="col">Cuota</th>
            <th scope="col">Identificador</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {allClients ? (
            allClients.map(client => (
              <tr key={client.id}>
                <td>{client.name}</td>
                <td>{formatThousands(client.cuota)}</td>
                <td>{client.id}</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => handleDeleteButton(client.id)}
                    className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                  >
                    Borrar
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))
          ) : (
            <p>Sin clientes</p>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Clients
```

This is the output I get on mount:

[image]

This is the initial value of allClients, I don't know why `Array [ {} ]`

Answer (score 0):

This is your current code:

```
allClients ? allClients.map : <p></p>
```

In contrast, this is what your code should be:

```
allClients.length ? allClients.map : <p></p>
```

allClients is an empty array so it returns true. Instead, your code should check allClients.length which actually returns the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the `useEffect` block. You add and empty object to the array the first time the component is rendered. That is why this condition `allClients.length > 0` is true:

> This is the initial value of allClients, I don't know why Array [ {} ]

**Solution 1:** Initialize `allClients` with `null`. Do the same with client. Check if client has value:

```
const [client, setClient] = useState(null)
const [allClients, setAllClients] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
   if(client) setAllClients([...allClients || [], client]);
}, [client]);
```

**Solution 2:** Initialize only client with null and then check for allClients.length > 0 to render the elements.

```
const [client, setClient] = useState(null)
const [allClients, setAllClients] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   if(client) setAllClients([...allClients, client]);
}, [client]);
```

**In both case you will need to check if client has a valid value.**

Comment: Also you can check if client has properties.